# Testflo fails 295 tests in openMDAO, openmdao module can't be found

Tags: openmdao

I'm a new user of openMDAO. I have installed the code using pip install openmdao in an environment I created. I have also installed Anaconda with Python version 3.x in that environment. When I run testflo after 'pip install testflo' it fails 295 tests, passes 177 and skips 0. I'm not sure if this is indicating I haven't installed openMDAO correctly or if it sometimes fails tests and that's okay. Also, when trying to run a tutorial script in spyder "'ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'openmdao'" occurs. Help is appreciated.

These are the steps I performed when setting up my environment and installing openMDAO:
1. bash Anaconda3-4.4.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
2. conda create –name test python=3.5
3.  Proceed ([y]/n)? ‘yes’
4. source activate test
5. conda install numpy scipy
6. pip install openmdao
7. spyder

Answer (score 0):

OpenMDAO 1.x releases should not be failing tests.
Which version of OpenMDAO?

I think from that last line, though, that it appears as though you had a problem with the installation.  If it can't find the openmdao module, then it's not installed correctly.  How or why it's installed wrong is difficult to diagnose without an output file or access to the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the instance of testflo that you're running is actually the one installed in the same environment as your OpenMDAO install.  We see this type of error from time to time when someone is running testflo from the system level for example.

Actually, I just noticed that you also mentioned having problems with accessing openmdao from spyder.  Is there any chance you forgot to activate the Anaconda environment where you installed OpenMDAO?  Otherwise, I would try reinstalling OpenMDAO and see if there are any error messages during install.